# Logical AND of multiple columns in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a dataframe(edata) as given below

```
Domestic   Catsize    Type   Count
   1          0         1      1
   1          1         1      8
   1          0         2      11
   0          1         3      14
   1          1         4      21
   0          1         4      31
```

From this dataframe I want to calculate the sum of all counts where the logical AND of both variables (Domestic and Catsize) results in Zero (0) such that

```
1   0    0
0   1    0
0   0    0
```

The code I use to perform the process is

```
g=edata.groupby('Type')
q3=g.apply(lambda x:x[((x['Domestic']==0) & (x['Catsize']==0) |
                       (x['Domestic']==0) & (x['Catsize']==1) |
                       (x['Domestic']==1) & (x['Catsize']==0)
                       )]
            ['Count'].sum()
           )

q3

Type
1     1
2    11
3    14
4    31
```

This code works fine, however, if the number of variables in the dataframe increases then the number of conditions grows rapidly. So, is there a smart way to write a condition that states that if the ANDing the two (or more) variables result in a zero then perform the sum() function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `np.logical_and.reduce` to generalise.

```
columns = ['Domestic', 'Catsize']
df[~np.logical_and.reduce(df[columns], axis=1)].groupby('Type')['Count'].sum()

Type
1     1
2    11
3    14
4    31
Name: Count, dtype: int64
```

---

Before adding it back, use `map` to broadcast:

```
u = df[~np.logical_and.reduce(df[columns], axis=1)].groupby('Type')['Count'].sum()
df['NewCol'] = df.Type.map(u)

df
   Domestic  Catsize  Type  Count  NewCol
0         1        0     1      1       1
1         1        1     1      8       1
2         1        0     2     11      11
3         0        1     3     14      14
4         1        1     4     21      31
5         0        1     4     31      31
```

Comment: Is it possible to use the `logical_and` for variables that has numerical values. For exampel if catsize column has values such as 0,2,4,5,6,8?

Comment: @eshfaqahmad convert the columns to bool first: df[col]=df[col].astype(bool)

Comment: thank you so much for the reply. I tried it, however this gives me some error as `KeyError: '[-1 -1 -2 -1 -2 -1 ] not in index`. I have changed the column "Catsize" to "Legs" and the values to 0,0,2,4,4,5.

Comment: @eshfaqahmad hi, I suggest opening a new question. You will get help a lot faster this way.

Comment: I have already asked a question about 3 days ago with no answer or comment yet.

Answer (score 5):

You can filter first using [`pd.DataFrame.all`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) negated:

```
cols = ['Domestic', 'Catsize']
res = df[~df[cols].all(1)].groupby('Type')['Count'].sum()

print(res)
# Type
# 1     1
# 2    11
# 3    14
# 4    31
# Name: Count, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

how about

```
columns = ['Domestic', 'Catsize']
df.loc[~df[columns].prod(axis=1).astype(bool), 'Count']
```

and then do with it whatever you want.

for logical AND the product does the trick nicely.
for logcal OR you can use `sum(axis=1)` with proper negation in advance.